# Microsoft Outlook - Add custom parameter authorization-request

Tags: php, authentication, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, oauth2client

I am using Microsoft Outlook rest php api to auth account and get user event.
I want to add custom parameters into the redirect URL.
I did not found any way to add custom parameters into the redirect url.

I am using this outlook/rest/php api - here is the url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial#implementing-oauth2

Here is the my controller AuthController.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
  public function signin()
  {
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
      session_start();
    }

    // Initialize the OAuth client
    $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
      'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
      'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
      'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
    ]);

    // Output the authorization endpoint
    echo 'Auth URL: '.$oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl();
    exit();
  }


public function gettoken()
{
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }

  // Authorization code should be in the "code" query param
  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // Check that state matches
    if (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth_state'])) {
      exit('State provided in redirect does not match expected value.');
    }

    // Clear saved state
    unset($_SESSION['oauth_state']);

    // Initialize the OAuth client
    $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
      'clientSecret'            => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
      'redirectUri'             => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
      'urlAuthorize'            => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlAccessToken'          => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY').env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
    ]);

    try {
      // Make the token request
      $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $_GET['code']
      ]);

      // Save the access token and refresh tokens in session
      // This is for demo purposes only. A better method would
      // be to store the refresh token in a secured database
      $tokenCache = new \App\TokenStore\TokenCache;
      $tokenCache->storeTokens($accessToken->getToken(), $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
        $accessToken->getExpires());

      // Redirect back to mail page
      return redirect()->route('mail');
    }
    catch (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
      exit('ERROR getting tokens: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    exit();
  }
  elseif (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    exit('ERROR: '.$_GET['error'].' - '.$_GET['error_description']);
  }
}
}
```

Here is the .env file details

```
OAUTH_APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD=YOUR_APP_PASSWORD_HERE
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8000/authorize
OAUTH_SCOPES='openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read'
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Kindly provide me some suggestions how to add custom param.

I need to add custom param with user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Azure auth folks would recommend using the `state` parameter, which is designed to do what you want. From https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow:

> `state`   A value included in the request that will also be returned in the token response. It can be a string of any content that you wish. A randomly generated unique value is typically used for preventing cross-site request forgery attacks. The value can also encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view they were on.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot when authenticating, Microsoft compares the redirect url with the one registered in the Microsoft App if they are different they request is rejected.

My suggestion would be to catch the authentication endpoint in your application and then do a redirection as needed based on the user's data from the /me endpoint.